# Logging someone else's google account on my Andoid device

Tags: authentication, android, google

Earlier today I had to add someones's Google account to my Android phone, to help them with something. My phone is a Samsung Galaxy S7 with the latest Android version, not sure if this is important. Anyway, I helped them and then immediately removed the new account from my device, the whole thing took 4-5 minutes at most.

Now, I know that when adding a new account Google tries to download things like contacts from the new account to the phone, but does it also try to do the opposite? I mean, upload any information from other existing accounts on the phone to the new account?

The other person does not have my login details and I use two factor authentication.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Google products will [not try to merge two separate accounts](https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/63304?hl=en) even if it is signed in on the same device. The only way to transfer data between two accounts is via [exporting from one account and importing to the other](https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/3024190).

Comment: sorry but i am confuse ..how your answer is related to OP's question ?

Comment: `I mean, upload any information from other existing accounts on the phone to the new account?` I meant, this type of upload does not automatically happen in any Google products.

Comment: Thank you, you have taken a load of my mind. I mean, that person is someone I trust, but I still started to get paranoid about what could happen.